# Purpose of "!::=::\" `name=value pair` in `env` stdout

Tags: bash, windows, environment-variables, msys

Inspecting the stdout the invocation of [`env`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/env.html) utility without supplying an operand it returned a `name=value` pair whose meaning I don't understand nor was able to find any documentation

```
$ env
...
!::=::\
...
TERM=cygwin
MSYSTEM_PREFIX=/mingw64
...
```

In the POSIX specification it is stated that

> ```
> STDOUT
>     If no utility operand is specified, each name= value pair in the
>     resulting environment shall be written in the form:
>
>     "%s=%s\n", <name>, <value>
> ```

I'm using `msysgit` on a machine running Windows 10.

```
$ git --version
git version 2.22.0.windows.1

$ printf "%s\n" $BASH_VERSION
4.4.23(1)-release
```

Started a new session and the result is the same.

Executing the same `env` command on cmd.exe returns

```
C:\>env
!::=::\
!C:=C:\
...
```

What is the meaning and purpose of this `name=value` pair?

Comment: Are you sure that's a name/value pair and not part of the value of something else? Environment variables' values can contain equal signs and newlines

Comment: On what system? What shell? I see you have tagged with POSIX, why? Are you using a POSIX shell on a POSIX system? Does this happen for all users or only you? Does it happen in a new session? I don't see this output on my Arch with bash nor on 2 Ubuntu systems I tried.

Comment: @terdon The reason for the POSIX tag is due to `env` utility being specified in the standard.

Comment: So this is something inherited from Windows ... I think this should be asked on [su] and is offtopic here.

Comment: Or maybe SO if it's some sort of git tool. In any case, that won't be a POSIX shell and it seems to be a specific issue with this git thing.

Comment: @JdeBP Yes it does. This question should be marked as duplicated.